# Jenkins Down - 'no space left on device' error

Tags: java, jenkins

Here when i tried to run Jenkins from command line, also ran

sudo systemctl restart jenkins
Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
but failed to start jenkins

```
XXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace$ /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080 --ajp13Port=-1
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx16000m
Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No space left on device
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:354)
at Main.copyStream(Main.java:394)
at Main.extractFromJar(Main.java:416)
at Main._main(Main.java:247)
at Main.main(Main.java:114)
leadschool_app@ip-10-0-67-70:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace$
```

---

```
XXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        30G   14G   16G  47% /
devtmpfs         16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.2G  354M  2.8G  12% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       34M   34M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552
/dev/loop4       71M   71M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21029
tmpfs            10M   10M   32K 100% /tmp
/dev/loop5       25M   25M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/4046
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/1001
/dev/loop8       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2128
/dev/loop9       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1081
/dev/loop10      68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21545
```

above is the space in my system,
how should I start my Jenkins?

Comment: It seems your temp folder is full? Perhaps try clearing it out

Comment: By temp folder I mean /tmp

Comment: steps to clean  /tmp folder

Comment: Just like you would any other folder.